# Sorting by value in multivalued field in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, scripting, elasticsearch

I have a multivalue field with integers in the document, for example

```
{
   values: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

I apply range filter, for example from 2 to 4 and get list of document with values, contains 2,3,4. 
Now I'd like to sort results, and first return documents, which contains 3.

I could do it using script sorting:

```
{
  sort:{
    _script: {
      script: "doc['values'].getValues().contains(3) ? 0 : 1",
      type: "number"
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't like it's performance, because `getValues()` returns a List actually, and `contains` methods is O(n).

Are any better ways?

Comment: did you find a better way to do this? I'm hitting the same situation. Thanks!

Comment: not really, but i'm out the project for a year.
I believe now it could be done somehow with aggregation framework

Comment: I ended up doing it with function_score and boost.

Comment: actually, you need to optimize your search results to run function_score on some limited number of values. Or make it somehow distributable

Comment: the values are 1 to 96. Is that limited enough? Do you mean somehow I should tell Elasticsearch what are the range of the values when mapping?

Comment: I mean that you need to organize your index to be able to use standard filtering as much as possible (for example precompute different combinations of input parameters or for the most popular search criteria if that too much). The main idea that filtering works very fast. If you have 1M documents and after filtering you have 1K, and then you use function_score  for 1K documents - that's ok. But if you run function_score on the whole 1M - it's slow